# Cannot find symbol in the chained exception

Tags: java, exception, chained

In the following program when we try to get the `main exception` means exception which cause the first exception of the program then it gives the error something like this : `cannot find symbol : e.getCause();` but after removing this statement `System.out.println("Main Cause : " + e.getCause());` we successfully get first exception.

```
class chain_demo {
    static void demo() {
        //create an exception
        ArithmeticException e = new ArithmeticException("top Module");

        //cuase an exception
        e.initCause(new NullPointerException("Cause"));

        //throw exception
        throw e;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            demo();
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            //display top_level exception
            System.out.println("Cautch : " + e);
        }

        //display cause exception
        //getting error here
        System.out.println("Main Cause : " + e.getCause());
    }
}
```

So, How can i get the cause exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `e` scope is limited only till the catch block
Move

```
System.out.println("Main Cause : " + e.getCause());
```

inside catch block E.g.

```
   try {
        demo();
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException e) {
        //display top_level exception
        System.out.println("Cautch : " + e);
        System.out.println("Main Cause : " + e.getCause());
    }
```

Comment: Oh......So mistakes ......Got it.....